# Allow git user only to create feature branches, commit and create pull requests

Tags: git, pull-request

How to allow git user only to create feature branches, commit on them and create pull requests?

All other actions should be not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If he/she is working on the same repo as yours, you can simply protect the master branch ([on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/) or [on BitBucket](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/) or [on GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/)).

That way, the colleague will *have* to work on a separate  branch.

One other easy solution is to enforce working on a **[fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)**, in which he/she can do anything, and can only contribute back to the original repo through [pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) (or [merge requests on GitLab](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/gitlab-basics/add-merge-request.html))